# Replace a DataTable in a DataSet

Tags: c#, database, dataset, dataadapter

-*Changed the question into a different simpler form*-

Please review this piece of code :

"Given Error"
**Error :**

*Update unable to find TableMapping['Table'] or DataTable 'Table'.*

The DataSet is Strongly typed,
We have a DataTable "dtNew" 
*[Made from a list "ListProducts", (No matter here !)]*

one column's name in the database differs from the list's field :
"Title" should mapped with the column : "TitleInDb"

```
SqlCeDataAdapter Adapter;
DsProducts Ds1Products ; // Strongly Typed
DataTable dtNew = new DataTable("Products");
DataColumn dc;
DataRow[] updRows;
// Fields : Name , Title, Price

dc = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string));
dtNew.Columns.Add(dc);
dc = new DataColumn("TitleInDb", typeof(string)); // The difference is by a reason
dtNew.Columns.Add(dc);
dc = new DataColumn("Price", typeof(string));
dtNew.Columns.Add(dc);
dtNew = updRows.CopyToDataTable();
Ds1Products.Tables.Add(dtNew);

// The Problems appear here :
// The Iteration is just for debugging phase and watching the changes which the columns are same 
   as before
foreach (var col in dtNew.Columns)
{
    Console.WriteLine(col.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(col.GetType());
}

// New Table is there, But here will come the Error
Adapter.Update(Ds1Products);
```

---

Running this, Iterating through the new columns I see that there is no change to the "Products" table which I thought should have been deleted at that time. Also the name of the new table `"dtNew"` seems to be `"table1"`

**Additional Notes :**
It uses Sql Compact 3.5
**The code is just a piece of code, Showing the exact problem !**

*please review the code and give your ideas on this,
I'm trying to make the whole database based on a refreshed Table (or DataRows[] )*

**Edit :**
**Replace a DataTable in a DataSet :** 
It means remove the first DataTable and Create new one and place it in !
Couldn't say easier ... (Based on a comment)

Comment: YOu are given an error. Nice. Shall I ask a crystal ball what error?

Comment: please look at 2 lines above the Additional Notes part, "Update unable to find TableMapping['Table'] or DataTable 'Table'." this is given by the VS.

Comment: The title is confusing, the content too. where is linq code here ? I think Adapter won't update if you change the schema.

Comment: I don't think so, may be you didn't see the new updated title or content, Here I didn't talk about the linq, May be you are right about the schema, Why I can't update ? which part is confusing you think, there was a table which we want to replace it with the new table we made recently. The new Title is : "Replace a DataTable in a DataSet", I changed this for simplifying more and leading to a direct simple answer not confusion :D

Comment: I know I am late to the party, but there may be others looking for an answer to this question.
It seems your question is incomplete.... There are 2 ambiguities here: 
1. We don't see `Ds1Products` getting initialized anywhere in the code.
2. You are talking of replacing a DataTable but in the code, we only see you are adding a new DataTable `dtNew` but never removing/replacing anything in the DataSet which is confusing.